# Polymorphic exception handling and compiler warnings

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-warnings

I have a small issue I'm not able to solve in a clean way.
I'm experimenting a bit with polymorphic exception handling, so I added a raise virtual function in my exception class that do the actual throwing and I replaced the throw with a raise() call.
Everything works as expected but then I applied this solution to a function with a return type with the following general form:

```
Obj Foo()
{
  if(true)
    return Obj
  else
  {
    //throw Exception; //With this call everything is fine
    Exception e{};
    e.raise(); //The compiler warns me that I do not return anything
  }
}
```

When I compile such a function the GCC compiler (v4.9) complains that Foo reaches the end without returning (-Wreturn-type)
Is there a way to convince the compiler that everything is ok, without hiding the warning away?

Comment: _Is there a way to convince the compiler that everything is ok, without hiding the warning away?_ Aren't these disjoint?

Comment: polymorphic exceptions? why? derive from `std::runtime_error` or `std::logic_error`. Then throw the exception you mean to throw - one exception type per problem type.

Comment: @erip: They are not disjoint because everything is actually ok, If I take the throw statement from the raise function to the body, the compiler recognizes that all the execution path return properly. If it's hidden in the raise() function the compiler complains

Comment: @Richard Hodges: I'm not sure you know what polymorphic exception handling means in this case. In case you don't you can take a look at this: http://www.drdobbs.com/polymorphic-exceptions/184401940 and understand why your comment is not relevant

Comment: @Triskeldeian the article is obsolete since c++11. You can call `std::rethrow_exception(std::current_exception());` to correctly re-throw the current exception.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `Exception.raise()` throws an exception and that you are using `true` to represent some expression that determines if an exception is not to be thrown (rather than the C++ keyword).  (since you have not mentioned the compiler complaining about a condition that is always true).

The obvious solution is to add a return statement after throwing the exception.

```
Exception e{};
e.raise();
return Obj;    // this will not be reached
```

Another option is to restructure your code so there is always a return path

```
if (!true)
{
     Exception e{};
     e.raise();       // or, alternatively, throw e
}
return Obj;
```

This way, for every execution path the compiler can detect, there is a valid return statement.

Comment: This seems the most reasonable to me.

Comment: Indeed, the second option is probably the only reasonable way to go.
I thought about the first option, but I don't like "spy values", even though they are never actually used. That's why I specifically said "a clean way"

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this, you can make each control path in the function return something that agrees with the return type, even if some conditionals can be shown to always be valid, or some paths can be shown to always throw exceptions. Here, your `else` path has no `Obj`-type return value.

Thus, after your `e.raise()`, you can return some value. If it is not possible to create a suitable value, consider making your function return [`optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional)`<obj>`.

Comment: "each control path needs to return something..." - no, that's not required. It's only if the returned value is **used** that the function has to return something sensible. There's nothing wrong with exiting a function by throwing an exception, regardless of whether it's done by `throw` or by a function call whose purpose is to throw the exception. The problem here is an overly-helpful compiler that applies non-rules.

Comment: Thanks, @PeteBecker I think you're correct. Will update accordingly.

Comment: @Pete Becker: +1. Only thing is that the compiler don't actually apply a constraint but just warns. Nonetheless the you are right

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need portability, and using gcc's compiler extensions are fine, then you can use the [gcc `noreturn` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes), which works with C and C++ functions:

```
class Exception {

// ...

   void raise() __attribute__ ((noreturn));

};
```